# Thread-breakpoints in intellij idea don't work

Tags: multithreading, intellij-idea

I've written a simple IRC-proxy for a single client with a built-in bot.
It spawns two threads, one reading from the client and feeding the server and the other doing the oppisite.

So far it works correctly. But if I put a breakpoint within the run()-methods of the thread-object, the IDE will never stop there. Breakpoints in the main-thread stop correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: need more problem specific details to answer this question. :))

Comment: No, what I write is sufficient. I put a breakpoint on a run()-function invoked by a new thread and the breakpoint is never hit. From the observed behaviour the code which has the attached breakpoint is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have the change the suspend policy for breakpoints to thread as documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/breakpoints-2.html#d1238020e140).

You would do this like so:

[image]

---

The following shows usage of the thread suspend policy. Notice how the Console does not have anything printed on it and also that ALL the threads have stopped on the breakpoint:

[image: Using <code>Thread</code> Suspend Policy]

---

The following shows the same breakpoint with the default `Suspend All` policy and how changing it to `Thread` on-the-fly results in stopping any threads that hit that breakpoint after that change:

[image]

Comment: The Suspend-policy is checked by default and I didn't have unchecked it. And if I chose that all threads stop or the thread where the breakpoint is hit stops doesn't matter here. But thanks nevertheless for your detailed answer.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have Supend checked AND the threads radio selected? The default is suspend checked and All selected, not thread. The default will not work you need to select Threads.